# jvm comparing String with StringBuffer.reverse() always fails

Tags: java, string, kotlin

I had a problem where I was to find all he substrings of a string that are palindromes. Input would always be 1 word. The test input was aabaa. I decided to try be clever and make a string buffer of my substring then use the reverse method to compare with the original using String.equals. It didn't work.

```
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val scan = Scanner(System.`in`)
    val input = scan.next()

    val found = ArrayList<String>()

    for (i in 0..input.length - 1) {
        for (j in 0..input.length - i) {
            val sub = input.substring(i, i + j)

            if (!found.contains(sub)) {
                // println(sub)
                found.add(sub)
                val rev = StringBuffer(sub).reverse()

                if (sub.equals(rev)) {
                    println(rev)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I uncomment the first print statement the output look like this using test input aabaa

```
a
aa
aab
aaba
aabaa
ab
aba
abaa
b
ba
baa
```

So I am getting the correct substrings, but the last if statement never resolves true and I don't know why this is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sub` is a String. `rev` is a StringBuffer. They can't be equal, since they don't even have the same type.

Additional notes:

- don't use StringBuffer. Use StringBuilder. StringBuffer is needlessly synchronized, and should not be used anymore (just like Vector shouldn't be used and ArrayList should be instead).
- `for (i in 0..input.length - 1)` can be written `for (i in 0 until input.length)` which is more elegant
- `input.substring(i, i + j)` can't be right: at the end of the two loops, i would be length - 1, and j would be length - 1, and you would thus take a substring between length - 1 and 2 * length - 2.
- to store unique results, use a HashSet, not an ArrayList. Calling contains() on a HashSet is O(1), whereas it's O(n) on an ArrayList.
- in Kotlin, unlike in Java, you can use `a == b` to test if a is equal to b, even if a and b are references.

Comment: Note that if you use a `Set` (as suggested), you don’t need the double-lookup like `if(!found.contains(sub)) { found.add(sub); … }` as you can use `if(found.add(sub)) { … }`. Further, you don’t need to insert a `toString()`, if you want to compare the contents. Just use [`sub.contentEquals(rev)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contentEquals-java.lang.CharSequence-). Since you only want to print it, and only if the two objects are equal, you can just use `if(sub.contentEquals(StringBuffer(sub).reverse())) { println(sub); }`